# sharepoint online workflow app installation error

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2015

I tried Visual Studio 2015 to create a Document approval workflow following [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456545(v=office.15).aspx) and once i done it.

I followed [this link](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/09/integrated-workflow-apps-deploy.html) to package the project and followed [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/office-365-how-to-set-up-an-app-catalog-on-sharepoint-2013/)  to create the App Catalog to upload the package file.
When trying to install it, show the installation error.

Referring the things above.

- Is there anything i missed?
- Is there any steps wrong?

The Error ScreenShots are as follows:

[image: Site Contents]

Error 1

[image: Error 1]

Error 2

[image: Error 2]